# Команда в matlab

Tags: python, matlab

Не могу понять что означает эта команда " b(a)=cc;", данная в примере:

```
cc=5;
a=1;
b(a)=cc;
```

как представить это в python'e?

Comment: В каком примере?

Comment: в том из трех строк

Comment: я не знаю что оно выведет

Comment: Понятно, что в том из тех строк :) откуда он взялся?

Comment: фрагмент кода, который нужно переписать из матлаба в питон.
спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Вот так это будет:

```
cc = 5
a = 1
b[a] = cc
```

Но нужно помнить, что если список `b` не инициализирован или содержит всего один элемент, то будет ошибка доступа.

Comment: я думаю, что `b` это словарь

Comment: Хм, может, и словарь @Danis